# Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0

Tags: android, kotlin, image-cropper

I add an image cropper in my application. But dispite using [this guide](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper), when I try to build the project, the following exception occurs:

```js
10: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/2.8.0/android-image-cropper-2.8.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/2.8.0/android-image-cropper-2.8.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0.

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1423)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$3600(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$DefaultResolutionHost.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:2035)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1395)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FilteredFileCollection.iterator(FilteredFileCollection.java:79)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf(ImmutableSet.java:257)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$1.visitCollection(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractFileCollection.java:335)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.lambda$calculateFinalizedValue$0(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:372)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.calculateFinalizedValue(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.isEmpty(CompositeFileCollection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.isEmpty(CompositeFileCollection.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.isEmpty(CompositeFileCollection.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.isEmpty(CompositeFileCollection.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultEmptySourceTaskSkipper.skipIfEmptySources(DefaultEmptySourceTaskSkipper.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.skipIfInputsEmpty(TaskExecution.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0.
Searched in the following locations:
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0.

  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/2.8.0/android-image-cropper-2.8.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/theartofdev/edmodo/android-image-cropper/2.8.0/android-image-cropper-2.8.0.pom
Required by:
    project :app

==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 719ms
23 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

It looks like there are problems in my build.gradle files but I can't figure out where exactly

build.gradle project file:

```js
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle module file (Image Cropper implementation is in the last line):

```js
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shercofaqapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0-beta03"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=compatibility']
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'

    //Material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.0-alpha01")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.0-alpha01")
    // Annotation processor
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.6.0-alpha01")

    def roomVersion = "2.4.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion")
    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$roomVersion")

    def nav_version = "2.5.0"
    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0")
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.0"

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1")

    implementation('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1')

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'

    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.1'
    // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1'
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.1.1'
    // Material Design
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    // Material design icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.1.1'
    // Integration with activities
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.0'
    // Integration with observables
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.1.1'

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.1.1"

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.1.1'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    kapt('com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0')

    //Google play-services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'

    //Image Cropper
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue has been opened. You can check: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/853

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper

You should do it by following the steps here:

## Add to your project

#### Step 1: Add the JitPack repository to your root build.gradle

```
  pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

#### Step 2: Add the dependency

```
  dependencies {
       implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.5.0'
  }
```

[Latest Release Version](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases)

It's worked.

Comment: Hmm... same problem: `> Could not find com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.2.1.`

Comment: You should use new version: 4.3.0 (https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases/tag/4.3.0)

Comment: Ofcourse I have tried it)) `> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/4.3.0/Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/4.3.0/Android-Image-Cropper-4.3.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app`

Comment: A issue has been opened on this topic: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/392

Comment: @Vaspit I updated the answer. It's working correctly. You can check.

Comment: Yes!)) I has answered this topic ( github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/392 ) the same. Thx for help

Comment: It is not mentioned that the settings.gradle contains ```dependencyResolutionManagement``` and not the build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

That library has not been updated in four years. You might want to consider a newer library, as there are [dozens of image-cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45?sort=created).

The reason why you cannot use it is because that library is not published in either the `google()` or `mavenCentral()` repositories, which is all that you have configured. You would have to add `jcenter()` to that list, and `jcenter()` is no longer a recommended repository.